# If a MiTM has server's cert, how can certificate pinning protect against this?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, certificate-pinning

In a scenario where client -> server through SSL, the server replies with the set of cert(chain-of-trust) which also contains the certificate pinned inside the client.

Let's say the Root CA is compromised and the setup is this : client -> MiTM -> server

Can't the MiTM just use the set of certs from the server to bypass certificate pinning? Does the pinned cert have to be the leaf-certificate in the chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the private key of the pinned certificate or one of its descendants is compromised then certificate pinning can't help you.

If the leaf-certificate is pinned, only getting the private key of this certificate allows MitM. If the intermediate certificate one level above is pinned, getting the private key of this intermediate **or** the leaf allows MitM.

Of course, pinning the leaf also makes it a lot harder to change that certificate.

As always, there is a trade off.